# fullcalendar with clickable popup on eventclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am having a popup form. I have events in fullcalendar page.

I need to pop up this form on click of any event from full calendar.

Have tried full calendar with modal but based on my requirement, i require my pop up form only.I tried with window.open("url"), but it goes to next page.

Here's my code but it need to create a clickable popup.I have added my form through an image below, which shall popup on click of event. kindly acknowledge me asap..

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ 

utc: true, 
header: { 
left: 'prev,next today EventButton', 
center: 'title', 
right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay' 
},   

editable: true, 
droppable: true, 

events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: '2016-07-01',
                end: '2016-07-01' 
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: '2016-07-07',
                end: '2016-10-08'
            }
        ],
eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
            console.log(event.id);
            window.open("<?php echo base_url() ?>common/calendar/form_calendar");
 }
});
});
```

[image: my sample form image]

Comment: try this `eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
            $('modelId').modal('show');
}`

Comment: would nt it pop up a modal form? i want to have a form of my own..

Comment: Form of your own means a  form page or a hidden form?

Comment: It is the 'form', which is in as a separate file. In normal pages i am achieving it through 'ajax link'. Is it possible to achieve that form in 'url' way on event click in fullcalendar? help me yaar

Comment: you can use iframe for it. Example : `$("iframe").attr("src", 'common/calendar/form_calendar');`

Comment: iframe? is it a property of jQuery..?

Comment: no its an HTML tag. Reference - http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp

Comment: $("iframe").attr("src", '<?php echo base_url() ?>common/calendar/form_calendar'); I gave this way and it hasnt work

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/RNe4T/6/

Comment: you can do whatever you like in the eventclick function, it's just normal javascript. So if you want to load your form via ajax in the same way as your other pages you can. Then it's up to you how to display it. If you don't like the modal idea, you could put the contents into a hidden div which shows up lower down the page, or you could temporarily hide the fullcalendar div and show the form div on its own. There are lots of ways to show/hide elements, you just need to decide on what suits you.

Comment: @ADyson, Yes, can you show me a sample code that the 'formpage' is opened through ajax call, upon eventClick...

Comment: @Keynes in your earlier comment you said "In normal pages i am achieving it through 'ajax link'." So whatever you do there, you can do something similar here as well if you want to. That's all I meant.

Comment: As an alternative, you can show a qTip2-generated tooltip, which can have HTML inside including form elements, buttons, links etc.